# How to get email Ids from google id

Tags: google-plus, google-signin

I have list of google Ids of users who have given a permissions for email access via android app.For all this google ids I want to fetch there emails which where miss to save while the user loged in on app. Is there any api through which I can get all the email Ids.

Comment: What do you mean by google ids? Refresh tokens? Account ids?

Comment: account ids.. Unique Id for google accounts.

Comment: You are still not expalining where did you get the id.

Comment: Hi I am getting google ids from android app we have recently launched, but while signing to app we skip to save email ids. Now we require email id of that google id.